# Spring Batch 5.x - No Scope registered for scope name 'job'

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to migrate Spring Boot 2 code to Boot 3, I am getting the below issue with Spring Batch jobs.

"java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'job'"

Below is the code. Is there a difference in Spring Batch 5, how JobScope/StepScopes are to be used? I couldn't understand this from the documentation.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class ProductFetcherJobConfiguration {

    private static int PRODUCT_CHUNK_SIZE = 20;

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Bean
    public Job productFetcherJob(JobRepository jobRepository) {
        return new JobBuilder("productFetcherJob", jobRepository)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(productLinkListFetcher(jobRepository, this.transactionManager))
                .next(downloadProductDocuments(jobRepository, this.transactionManager, productWebDownloadReader(), productWebDownloadProcessor(), productWebDownloadWriter()))
                .listener(productFetcherJobListener())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step productLinkListFetcher(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new StepBuilder("productLinkListFetcher", jobRepository)
                .tasklet(productLinkListFetcherTask(), transactionManager)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step downloadProductDocuments(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager, ItemReader<String> productWebDownloadReader,
                              ItemProcessor<String, String> productWebDownloadProcessor,
                              ItemWriter<String> productWebDownloadWriter) {
        return new StepBuilder("downloadProductDocuments", jobRepository).<String, String> chunk(PRODUCT_CHUNK_SIZE, transactionManager)
                .reader(productWebDownloadReader)
                .processor(productWebDownloadProcessor)
                .writer(productWebDownloadWriter)
                .listener(productWebChunkListener())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ProductDownloadChunkListener productWebChunkListener() {
        return new ProductDownloadChunkListener();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ProductListFetcherTask productLinkListFetcherTask() {
        return new ProductListFetcherTask(cacheManager());
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ProductDownloadReader productWebDownloadReader() {
        ProductDownloadReader productWebDownloadReader = new ProductDownloadReader();
        productWebDownloadReader.setName("productWebDownloadReader");
        return productWebDownloadReader;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ProductDownloadProcessor productWebDownloadProcessor() {
        return  new ProductDownloadProcessor(cacheManager());
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ProductDownloadWriter productWebDownloadWriter() {
        return  new ProductDownloadWriter(cacheManager());
    }

    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public ProductFetcherJobListener productFetcherJobListener() {
        return new ProductFetcherJobListener(cacheManager());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a difference in Spring Batch 5, how JobScope/StepScopes are to be used?

No, there is no difference in behaviour. However, there is a difference in the way Spring Batch is configured with Spring Boot 3. See migration guide here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#spring-batch-changes

You are using `@EnableBatchProcessing`, which means the auto-configuration of Spring Batch is not activated (including batch scopes registration). If you want to use `@EnableBatchProcessing`, you need to configure Spring Batch manually, including batch scope registration.

Comment: Ok thanks. Let me remove @EnableBatchProcessing. One related question though, if I want a step to create a new bean/instance each time the job runs (sometimes simultaneously), do I still need to add the scope annotation to the Step? Or thats not needed? (eg. In the above code, if 20 instances of ProductFetcherJob is started at the same time with different job parameters, how to make sure each of them gets a new bean for ProductListFetcherTask?)

Comment: The step itself does not need to be scoped, it is rather the component of the step that should be scoped (tasklet, item reader, writer, etc). In your case, `ProductListFetcherTask` is the tasklet of the step, which should be step scoped (as it the case now). No need to scope everything, only scope beans that need late binding.